# What statistical model can be used to find how following variables relate?

Tags: multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics

I want to find the relationship between a disease incidence in a region and a number of other environmental factors such as temperature, elevation etc.

I have tables containing this data for a particular country. The data files are raster files of the country map with each pixel having certain numeric value for the particular parameter. Example [126, 540, 359...] say disease cases or [23.34, 19.02...] for temperature etc.

I have read about **multiple regression**, **Pearson Chi square test**, **t-tests** etc. But I didn't find them suitable: Multiple regression because what I read it assumes a linear relationship between the variables. Chi square test applies to categorical data. t-tests for small datasets. I've also read about **EOF analysis** (Empirical Orthogonal Function) but it requires time series data. **CCA** (Canonical Correlation Analysis) but it finds the relationship between two sets of multiple variables.

**Which statistical method can I use to find the relationship between these variables?** I want to use a method that gives a relationship, say, more is the elevation, more is the number of disease incidence etc. Without assuming anything before hand like, "there'd be a linear relationship between the variables, so using linear relationship model." *Also, is some method I mentioned appropriate but my understanding is not correct?*

I don't necessarily need to find relationship one to many, it'd be fine to use one on one methods. On a side note, I'm working with GIS data and would use Python or R modules to find and plot the relationship. Also, the arrays don't have same size. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the total population for each pixel?

Comment: I do not have population with each pixel. A pixel either has values of some cancer cases or temperature values or radiation values etc.

Comment: Then you should get them, unless each pixel is of equal population. For instance, if you have a pixel with 1,400 cases in it and another one with 140, the analysis will show the 1,400 cases pixel as a big jump, but in reality it's because there are 100,000 people living in that pixel, but only 10,000 in the other one. Without using the population as "offset," it would be hard to analyze the data.

Comment: I used Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) Interpolation to counter this. Now not a single pixel but a lot of pixel have same or decreasing value as we go far away from that center. I think it should not be a problem because for each pixel in one file I have cancer cases and for same pixel in another file I have temperature or radiation values. Now I want to relate such values for each pixel for whole country.